# Are externs (global variables) ever justifiable?

Tags: c++, programming-practices, variables, globals

Under which circumstances would you deem it justifiable to use externs (i.e. global variables)?

For example, in a system with 1 given state at a time, would it be appropriate to store this state in an extern?

Comment: When you need the benefits that an `extern` provides, and those benefits outweigh the costs.

Comment: Note that your question is an exact duplicate of [this question on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10422034).

Comment: `std::cout` as one example. I'd hate to have to initialize a console object every time I wanted to output something in a quick test project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need an `extern` global variable, if:

- an element of the program's state (i.e. the global variable content) needs to be shared, AND
- it is not possible to manage these elements as a static class member (by preference a private or protected one), AND
- it is not possible to afford the overhead of encapsulating it into a singleton, AND
- there's no easy way to make the objects/function that deal with that state to know each other and communicate directly instead of using the global, AND
- it is not desirable to regroup the classes/functions that need this state into the same compilation unit (which could at least reduce the risk of unexpected side effects, by making that global variable `static` and thus less visible).

Alternatively, you might need an `extern volatile` global variable for the same reasons, but if it's about the system state (e.g. fixed location used by hardware)